# Manipulate a javascript regex match e.g. $1 before replacing

Tags: javascript

I have a line of `javascript` that replaces matches as follows:

```
var str = "some string"
str.replace(/\[b\]((?:.|\n)+?)\[\/b\]/gmi, '**$1**')
```

Is it possible to manipulate the value in `$1` before it is processed?

For example, I would like to run a standard `.replace()` on the value in `$1`, like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
str.replace(/\[b\]((?:.|\n)+?)\[\/b\]/gmi, '**$1.replace('x', 'y')**')
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: `.replace` takes a callback, the match will be an argument.

Comment: please add some results.

Comment: @elclanrs, that is an answer, so why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to elclanrs, I got it working. For example:

```
str.replace(
 /\[b\]((?:.|\n)+?)\[\/b\]/gmi, 
 function(match, m1, m2){return '[' + m2 + '](' + m1.replace(/ /gmi, '%20') + ')';}
)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter